# Installing sublime text plugins all at once

Tags: plugins, text-editors, sublime-text-2

Is there a way to install all the sublime text 2 plugins that you would like to install all at once. In Notepad++, there is a plugin manager which lets you install all the plugins you want to install by checking the box next to the plugin name & description. I was wandering if there is something like that for sublime text.

For eg, I would like to install Zen Coding, JQuery Package for Sublime Text, Sublime Prefixr, JS Format, SublimeLinter and many other plugins all at once rather than typing each plugin in the Package Control and installing it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

With Package Manager, you have to go one by one.

Since you want a bunch of plugins, I assume you've used them already. In that case, you can easily back them up and copy back.

The package files can be found at `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages`. You can access them from command pallete by selecting `Browse Packages`.

Comment: I already knew how to backup packages but was looking for a way to install all the packages at once as it is a pain installing plugins one by one.

Comment: @Ishan it really is. Try posting it on userecho or at sublime forums.